# Округление числа до десятых в Javascript

Tags: javascript, калькулятор

**Здравствуйте!**

У меня есть некая форма для вычисления площади по ширине и длине. И функция Javascript для вычисления.

Все отлично работает, вот только нужно, чтобы результат вычисления был не более 2 знаков после запятой. Пробовал внедрить в функцию **.toFixed(2)**, но ничего не получается - не знаю куда её привадить.

Подскажите как лучше сделать, а то знаний в javascript маловато - только учусь ещё.

```
    <div class='controls'>
      <input type="text" id='dlin' onkeyup='Rech()' value="1" style="width: 30px;"/> х 
      <input type="text" id='shir' onkeyup='Rech()' value="1" style="width: 30px;"/> м
      <span style="margin-left:50px;">Площадь потолка:<span id='ploshad'>0</span> м<sup>2</sup></span> 
    </div>
    <script language="JavaScript">
function Rech()
{
document.getElementById('ploshad').innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById('dlin').value)*parseFloat(document.getElementById('shir').value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Rech() {
    var ploshad = document.getElementById('ploshad'),
        dlin = parseFloat(document.getElementById('dlin').value),
        shir = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shir').value);
    ploshad.innerHTML = (dlin * shir).toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

.toFixed(2) ставьте там, где нужно уже непосредственно вывести результат, до этого пусть будет с максимально возможной точностью.

Comment: Нужно здесь вместо ноля, может подскажешь как?
<span style="margin-left:50px;">Площадь потолка:<span id='ploshad'>0</span> м<sup>2</sup></span>